# Cannot send message to TCP server

Tags: autoit

I work in a travel agency and we have been using Autoit for a while. We have a working TCP server made with Autoit but our client doesn't work.

Here's the faulty code

```
$port = 1942

$addr = 192.168.101.111

$connexion = TCPConnect($addr, $port)

TCPSend("bus has arrived")

TCPCloseSocket($connexion)
```

Comment: Looks like this code is not nearly enough to actually investigate your issue. Also beware that your formatting has cause the automated systems to consider this spam so you have a second reason to edit.

Comment: @PaulStelian how to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting questions, you can use the '{}' button located in the message toolbar and put your code in there so It can be read better.

Regarding your question, there are several mistakes and things you've missed out in the code.

When you want to do anything regarding TCP/UDP in AutoIT - you first need to start their services, then later shut them down.

In many programming languages, string variables require two "" at the start and end of the string. The same is with AutoIT.

When using **TCPSend** , the first parameter is the socket and the second is the message that it will send.

Here is an example script I've written. Feel free to modify it. I've also commented stuff out.

```
#Include <ButtonConstants.Au3>
#Include <EditConstants.Au3>
#Include <GUIConstantsEx.Au3>
#Include <StaticConstants.Au3>
#Include <WindowsConstants.Au3>
#Include <GUIEdit.Au3>
#Include <Misc.Au3>
#NoTrayIcon
Opt ('GUIOnEventMode', 1)

;We are using Input boxes so the user can type in the IP/Port/Msg and they will be stored as variables for later use
$IP = InputBox("SO TCP Connector", "Receiver's IP Address", "0.0.0.0", "", _
         - 1, -1, 0, 0)
$Port = InputBox("SO TCP Connector", "Receiver's Port", "80", "", _
         - 1, -1, 0, 0)
$Message = InputBox("SO TCP Connector", "Message to send", "Sample text", "", _
         - 1, -1, 0, 0)

;Starting the TCP service
TCPStartup()

;Opening a socket
$iSocket = TCPConnect($IP, $Port)

;Sending our message
TCPSend($iSocket, $Message)

;Closing the socket from before
TCPCloseSocket($iSocket)

;Stopping the TCP Service
TCPShutdown()
```

Comment: why using inputboxes?

Comment: @AnneSkeitzig I said its an example that you can use and modify if you want to. I am using the Input boxes to avoid having to edit the script each time the server changes its IP/Port and also to avoid having to edit it for a new message.

Comment: but will it work if i use '$port = 1942' and '$ip = 192.168.100.111'?

Comment: @AnneSkeitzig The first would work, the second wouldn't because its a string, and strings need two " " around them. So it needs to be '$ip = "192.168.100.11" for it to work. Do you have any other questions?

Comment: @AnneSkeitzig No problem, glad I could help. If an answer has worked for you, then you should accept it by clicking the checkmark below the upvote and downvote buttons.